# How do I combine 40000 update queries into one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create a new column of data, assigning every 15 minutes in my data a new number. There are about 40,000 15-minute time bins to be assigned... Here is what I have so far.

```
UPDATE [Groupers final no summer] 
SET [Groupers final no summer].[Fifteen min time bin daily] ='1',
WHEN [Groupers final no summer].[DateTimeEDT]=Between #11/02/05 08:45:01# 
     and #11/02/05 09:00:00#) 
OR 
SET [Groupers final no summer].[Fifteen min time bin daily] ='2', 
WHEN [Groupers final no summer].[DateTimeEDT]=Between #11/02/05 09:00:01# 
    and #11/02/05 09:15:00#);
```

And the time bins would go up to 40,000.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to assign each 15 minute interval a unique number. Is that right?

Comment: The only thing is that there will be multiple dada points with the same fifteen minute time bin value (which is what I want). So if I have, say, 18 data points between 8:45 and 9:15, they will all be assigned the number 1, then any data points between 9:15 and 9:30 are assigned number 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is how I finally did it!

I converted the Date/Time to Julian calendar using CVDate() and made that a new column. I then converted using [Julian date/time]/(15/(60*24)) to calculate the number of 15 minute time bins I had in another column, and then called my first date/time 0 and counted fifteen minute time bins in integers by doing

Int([15 minute time intervals]-3711251)

where 3711251 is the first 15-min integer before my actual start time.

I hope this makes sense...

I am thrilled to have solved this and didn't want to leave this thread without saying thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to turn the value in `[Groupers final no summer].[DateTimeEDT]` into seconds since the start time, then you can:

```
UPDATE [Groupers final no summer]
SET [Groupers final no summer].[Fifteen min time bin daily] = timeInSeconds / (15*60)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query computes the time bin based on the 15 min time interval. It uses [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to return the number of seconds between the two timestamps. If you are not using mysql, your rdbms most likely has something equivalent, for example, SQL Server has [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

```
UPDATE [Groupers final no summer] 
    SET [Groupers final no summer].[Fifteen min time bin daily] =((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, #11/02/05 08:45:01#, DateTimeEDT)/(15*60))+1
```

Before running the update query, you might try this as a select query, to verify the results are correct:

```
SELECT * FROM [Groupers final no summer], 
((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, #11/02/05 08:45:01#, DateTimeEDT)/(15*60))+1 AS TimeBin
```

Comment: OK, I will try this. I am using Microsoft Access SQL

Comment: Access supports DateDiff. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php